# Could not access webservice through client from weblogic server

Tags: web-services, weblogic, jax-ws, webservice-client

I am trying to access a webservice from my unix machine and the web services are hosted in an apache server. I followed the post [javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL. Response: '401: Unauthorized'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882360/javax-xml-ws-webserviceexception-failed-to-access-the-wsdl-response-401-una) since i faced the same problem of Response with error code 401. But still my issue is not resolved. I tried the solution given by Paulius Matulionis in that post. But, still stuck with establishing the service.

Additional info:
1. Using Weblogic server at client end.
2. Also we are using IBM JVM.

Thanks in advance
Amalraj

Comment: i hope this link will help you --> http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/401error.htm

Comment: Can you post a trace of the HTTP headers showing what type of authentication is being used?